# How to dynamically insert div in a table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a div with a dynamic ID to a table cell.

This is how I do it right now:

```
var ringNr = 1;
function tableCreate(){
alert('tableCreate');
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.id = "ring0" + ringNr;
newDiv.style.height = "40px";
newDiv.innerHTML = "Hello";

$("#shoppingCart tbody").append(
    "<tr>"+
    "<td>"+this.appendChild(newDiv)+"</td>"+ //This line creates the error
    //More cells to add
    "</tr>");
ringNr++;
};
```

this.appendChild(newDiv) raises the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'appendChild'`

How can I add this div to my table cell without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
"<tr>"+
"<td>"+this.appendChild(newDiv)+"</td>"+ //This line creates the error
//More cells to add
"</tr>");
```

You are building a string. If you want to append, you need to create an element.

```
var tr = $("<tr/>");
var td = $("<td/>");
td.append(newDiv);
tr.append(td);
$("#shoppingCart tbody").append(tr);
```

Comment: This works :) But I want to add more td's before the closing </tr>. How can I add this new <td> without adding the closing </tr> ?

Comment: You keep appending tds. You do not "close" the tr.

Comment: No, using your code there's automatically a closing <tr/> appended. See: http://piclair.com/data/p61ot.jpg

Comment: Review DOM when you have time with appendChild method. You can add as many as you want... `tr.append(td1); tr.append(td2); tr.append(td3); tr.append(td4);`

Comment: I understand :) Thx a lot epascarello!